# Voronoi and distance to the nearest point

Tags: coordinate-system, gis-principle, voronoi-thiessen

I was convinced that Voronoi polygons were created so that each location in a polygon is closer to the origin point present in that polygon than to any other seeds

In Snow's famous case study in Soho, London (see screenshot), when I compare the Voronoi partitioning to the distances to the nearest point, I realize that some deaths (red figures) are in the polygon of a pump (white figure) while they are closer to another pump.

How can this be explained?

[image]

Map projection is EPSG 3857 (WGS84). Reprojection to British national grid gives me the same result.

Comment: how are you calculating the distances?

Comment: Map projection or data/calculation projection (BTW EPSG 3857 is a Mercator projection with highly distorted measurements in meters, not degrees on an ellipsoid like WGS84)? Can you replicate the result in other software?

Comment: It is not the map projection that matters but the data projection. Have you tried reprojecting the data first?

Comment: My data have different projections.

Comment: Ok, works great with save as  and all data with EPSG 3857 (WGS84)

Comment: @JGH OK great advice. Can you put this in answer ?

Comment: @JGH OK. Can you put this in answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the map projection that matters but the data projection.

As a rule of thumb, for any processing, all data must be in the same projection even if some tools allow some sort of on-the-fly reprojection. 3857 should however not be used for anything related to distances, as it highly distorts them.